# SBCL Unbound variable in a macro

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

Im trying to create a macro that checks for the function definition that it gets passed in. I am new in lisp and I got stuck at checking whether or not `defun` is the first element in the list

```
(defmacro check (fun-param)
    (first fun-param)
)

(format t "~a~%" (check '(defun my-function (x y))))
```

From this I was expecting to get 'defun' but I get quote is unbound error. I then used `eval` inside the `first` to evaluate it but I got a "defun" is unbound error. I tried many steps like checking if the parameter is a list with `(listp fun-param)`.

What I want to do is check if the first element is "defun" I tried `(if (equal (first fun-param) "defun"))` but it does not work either so I would like some guidance on what is going on. The way I am calling the check macro is the way I am being asked to call it so that is to be unchanged.

Comment: Why are you doing this with a macro? This should be an ordinary function.

Comment: Since you are passing `(quote (defun my-function (x y)))` and the macro does `(first fun-param)` the expected new code to replace the whole thing is `quote`. I don't think quote is a bound variable, but you can define it eg. `(defparameter quote 'test)` and your code should evaluate to `test`. You code does not make any sense tho :-o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Macro or Function?**

Typically when we have a piece of code (as data) and what to check syntactic correctness (like it being a list which begins with a `defun`), then we can write a function.

```
(check '(defun my-function (x y))
```

Above most definitely should be a function. The code is quoted data and we can call the function to return a result.

Also the name of the function, here `check`, should indicate an action.

*Rule: choose a function*

- data + runtime result -> write a function

Slightly different it is when we want to make it a macro to transform the passed code (which expands into more code) and we want to make sure that the passed code is well formed.

*Rule: choose a macro*

- code transformation + syntactic check at compile time -> write a macro

A macro form would not need a quoted form, just the form itself is sufficient.

If we write a macro, then we also need to think about the naming. It's not a function and it will usually have different purposes: to define something (`DEFVAR`, `DEFCLASS`, ...), to set up a scope (`WITH-OPEN-FILE`, ...), to provide a new control structure (`LOOP`, `DOLIST`, ...), ...

**Example**

Let's say you want to check the form at macro expansion time. Thus we check if the form is a list and if the first element is `defun`.

Since `defun` is a symbol, we need to compare it to the symbol `defun`, not to the string `"defun"`. Symbols are not strings and strings are not symbols. Identifiers in Lisp source code are symbols, not strings.

We then also return `nil` as the macro expanded form to execute, since this is only a simplified example. `nil` then evaluates to `nil`.

```
(defmacro checking (fun-param)
  (cond ((not (listp fun-param))
         (error "~a is not a list" fun-param))
        ((not (eq (first fun-param) 'defun))
         (error "DEFUN is missing in ~a" fun-param)))
  nil)
```

Thus:

```
CL-USER 27 > (checking (defun my-function (x y)))
NIL

CL-USER 28 > (checking (foobar my-function (x y)))

Error: DEFUN is missing in (FOOBAR MY-FUNCTION (X Y))
  1 (abort) Return to top loop level 0.

Type :b for backtrace or :c <option number> to proceed.
Type :bug-form "<subject>" for a bug report template or :? for other options.

CL-USER 29 : 1 >
```

Comment: _"Symbols are not strings...."_ -- But symbols can be string designators, which might be confusing ;)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and example I see the quote as redundant now, that makes sense. When I did not include the quote however, I was getting the DEFUN is unbound. Why was that the case? How does it work? Was it because I was printing the symbol outside the macro?

Comment: @ran123: your macro `CHECK` expanded `(defun my-function (x y))` to  the symbol `defun`. Then evaluation of the symbol `defun` is causing an error, because the symbol `defun` is unbound.

Comment: If I wanted to use (format t"....) inside the macro to print the data when it encounters a problem instead of throwing an error (part of assignment) could I do so or is it bad? when I do it works fine but I feel I should not be using it in there as macros are supposed to return code and this feels more like a function.

Comment: @Ran123: if you want diagnostic output during compilation or at runtime when using an interpreter, then your macro can create that output as a side effect. Otherwise it would be better if it is silent...

Answer (score 1):

Macros are supposed to return new code to be executed. Use backtick to return code with a template.

```
(defmacro check (fun-param)
  `(first ,fun-param)
)
```

Your code is calling `first` at compile time and returning `quote`, since it's receiving `(quote (defun ...))` as its argument. Then it tries to use `quote` as a variable in the `format` argument.